# How can i create touchevents in certain areas of the screen in android?

Tags: android

I have a neat background for my app with the "buttons" already included in the background.

I would like to surround these "buttons" with a bounding box or rectangle somehow and then have that area respond to a touch event.

How can i do this in android?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simply surround it with any layout and setOnClickListener for that layout.

As an example

```
 <LinearLayout 
   android:background="#abc123"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:paddingBottom="10dp"
   android:paddingTop="10dp"
   android:id="@+id/lay1">

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Now put separate listeners for the button and the linear layout.This will be consistent with all the screens i.e the padding will be fixed everywhere.

Comment: That depends on your way of creating the layouts.Jst stay away from giving fixed dimensions.

Comment: how do i surround the different parts of the background with any layout?

Comment: i try to wrap the layouts around my background elements but they don't resize the way i want them to. Now they do resize the way i want them to, but they are always shifted back up to the top left corner of the screen. I can't get them to surround the elements i need them to.

Comment: I don't want a button, i just need to be able to touch the screen (not a button) and trigger some code. I already have it working with buttons, but now with the new background i need to be able to touch portions of the background and trigger the touchevents

Answer (score 0):

1. Add button in XML
2. Attach Click Listener
3. Run Application

For more information and help click [here](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-button-example/)

EDIT: Code for run

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.but_1_but:
        // do stuff for 1st button
        break;
    case R.id.but_2_but:
        // do stuff for 2nd button
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have already done this, but now i need the code that runs when the button is clicked to happen when a certain area of my background is touched

Comment: my dear friend, i do not want to use a button. However i have found a solution and i will be posting it shortly

Answer (score 0):

Add a **View** (This will be transparent and will sit on top of all your view components) to your layout. And set a **OnTouchListener** to your View. Then listen for touch events within the expected X, Y co-ordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Try and use

```
Region rgn = new Region();
```

In this ,set a boundary  which should be with in the button.

And check a condition that if your click is within the x and y  of this region ,do  something...

Refer

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/2D-Graphics/Regions.htm